# C++ access to a class declared and defined inside cpp file

Tags: c++, class, visibility

i'm working on a project with third party libraries that use some scripts where **classes are 
declared and defined inside .cpp files**. They initialize these classes using an external constructor function that registers the instances inside an iterator to be executed on trigger events.

In this way these class seems to be not accessible from external files. **But i need to use them using a not invasive method**, **in some way that not require to rewrite third-party code**.

this is the pseudo scenario:

"Script.cpp"

```
#include "ScriptLoader.h"
class theirScript {
    public:
        theirScript() : RegisterScript("theirScript") {}

        static void anUsefullStaticMethod() { ... }
}

void addTheirScript() {
    new theirScript();
}
```

"ScriptLoader.h"

```
void addTheirScript();
```

"ScriptLoader.cpp"

```
#include "ScriptLoader.h"
addTheirScript();
```

"MyFile.cpp"

```
#include "ScriptLoader.h"
theirScript::anUsefullStaticMethod(); // will never work
```

**how can i access to "theirScript" class then? is there a way where i don't have to rewrite their code?**

Comment: This library was intentionally written to stop you from doing this.  Maybe to provide an interface callable from a C program.  Maybe to stop you deriving your own class and stop the risk of you breaking the base class.  It isn't very clear which, you are yelling for help in a crowded football stadium.  You should contact the programmer of this library instead.

Comment: Talk to the vendor of the libraries. :-)